# Accidentally deleted python, python2, python2.7 files from /usr/bin/. Is it possible to recover them?

Tags: python, yum

I accidentally deleted python, python2, python2.7 files from /usr/bin/. 
Now yum is also not working.

Is it possible to recover them?

Comment: Belongs on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just reinstall the lot?

Comment: @emilio m bumachar- neither yum nor rpm working. Tried compiling from source, but I guess there is some problem with the path configuration. M confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot recover the files, if you really deleted them. If you have no backup at hand, and you don't want to reboot from the installation disc, you can still try to copy it over from a different installation of the same OS:

```
cp /path/to/your/copy/python2.7 /usr/bin
ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

It should be the same OS and distribution for the same processor family and type.

If that fails, you can still boot from the installation disc and re-install Python.

Comment: Thanks! I installed a VM with same OS and copied the missed files(including /usr/lib/python2.7 directory). Now it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

*Generally* on UNIX-like systems, deleting a file means it cannot be retrieved. (Unless you are using a filesystem that has the ability to take [snapshots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snapshot_%28computer_storage%29#File_systems), and you are using them.)

Restore the files from your most recent backup.

Answer (score 0):

If `yum` and `rpm` aren't working you can always download the *rpm* packages for `python` and/or `python2.7`for your `arch` (from your distro repositories), extract their contents, inside you should find the executable(s) you have deleted from your system. Just copy them in /usr/bin, `chmod 755` and you're done.

Comment: ok.. This too is a good solution. But anyways I installed a VM with same OS and copied the missed files(including /usr/lib/python2.7 directory). Now it is working fine. Thanks anyways..

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, yum will stop working for centos users.

Then, copy /usr/bin/python and /usr/bin/python2.7 from another virtual machine (same OS), and paste that to /usr/bin (from where you deleted).

Also, give read and execute permission to both files,

```
$ chmod 755 /usr/bin/python*
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use: sudo rpm --reinstall -v http://rpmfind.net/linux/centos/7.9.2009/updates/x86_64/Packages/python-2.7.5-90.el7.x86_64.rpm. See http://rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/centos/updates/7.9.2009/x86_64/Packages/python-2.7.5-90.el7.x86_64.html for more packages